# How to trace resolving process of nuget package references

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a solution with multiple projects in it (~400). A lot of them are using `newtonsoft.json` library. Some of them are using different version of the library. In a host project for web app, there is no direct reference to `newtonsoft.json`. Also, I believe, there are dependencies to packages that depend on `newtonsoft.json`. However, in bin folder of that project I began getting `newtonsoft.json 9.0` instead of `newtonsoft.json 11.0` as it used to be. And it causes load exception in runtime due to invalid version. If I include direct reference to `newtonsoft.json 11.0`, it still puts version 9.0 in the bin folder even if I clear all bin,obj folders. I use PackageReference for managing dependencies, and everything is in .`net 4.6.1`; I use binding redirects to resolve issues with different versions of the same library.

My question is if there is a way to diagnose how particular dll of package ref appears in bin folder? I would like to see some sort of comprehensive trace of dependency resolution so that I can fix it without using "trial and error" approach.

**Upd.**

Actually, thanks guys for pointing to structured logging. You are the best! So the issue was that one of the project had `<OutputPath>` pointing to the `bin` folder of the host project. So when the project was built, it was overriding binaries in the host project. Apparently, build order has changed due to continuous reference shuffling and the project with wrong `<OutputPath>` started building last. To find this out 1) I Newtonsoft.Json was recorded in `DoubleWrites` section 2) analyzing location from double writes I found out in `_CopyFilesMarkedLocal` section

```
Copying file from "\VenomousProject\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to "HostProject\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
```

That was it.

Comment: `If I include direct reference to newtonsoft.json 11.0, it still puts version 9.0 in the bin folder even if I clear all bin,obj folders.` I would double check this. Because I don't think this should be be the case, normally. Either this, or some project is importing Json.NET as a non standard Nuget package (maybe a local reference?). Don't know about tools doing what you ask, besides the usual Manage Nuget Packages for Solution. I think you could have more luck trying to expand recursively the project and Nuget dependencies on your startup project.

Comment: Been there. :( This happens when there is no direct or indirect build dependency between two projects that produce different versions of a package. The last project that finishes building  "wins" and produces the final version of the dll. I used "trial and error" as well to see who produces the unwanted version of the dll: building projects one by one, then based on dependencies, skip the projects that were build etc. And after I determined the project(s), I also needed to inspect the hierarchies of Nuget packages. I'm also curious what other options might be to trace this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer (https://msbuildlog.com/)

- build the project from command line with `msbuild -bl` - you will get `msbuild.binlog`
- open the binlog with the log viewer and use the dll name as a search term
- inspect all records related to the dll and backtrack a place (project and msbuild' target) where the wrong file version is taken.

Answer (score 1):

With `PackageReference`, NuGet will write a file named `project.assets.json` in the project's `obj` folder. This file is used by the rest of the build to determine what files from packages should be included in the build, but it also contains a list of all the packages that were selected, what version was selected, and what dependencies each package has (package id and version). This is the closest thing to dependency resolving debugging that NuGet has.

In the file, search for `"Newtonsoft.Json/`, and you should find which version of Newtonsoft.Json that NuGet selected. Remove the `/` and replace it with `"`, and you can find all the packages that have dependencies on Newtonsoft.Josn. Search for `newtonsoft.json.dll` to find all the packages that ship that dll in its package (sometimes package authors perfer to ship multiple dlls in their package, rather than adding dependencies, which prevents NuGet from being able to version selection.

If there are multiple packages with which contain a dll with the same filename, NuGet will tell MSBuild about all of them, and it's up to MSBuild to select which one to use (pass to the compiler and copy to the bin/publish directory). As [@Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011071/serg) wrote [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005824/2843065), you can use binlogs (with the `-bl` argument on any MSBuild command, including `dotnet restore` or `dotnet build`). NuGet's inner workings are not output to MSBuild, so when your package graph has multiple packages that list Newtonsoft.Json as a dependency, it won't tell you why NuGet chose a specific version, but binlogs are very useful at debugging other build related issues.